# Scheduled database polling with WSO2 Data Services Server is not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I am working on the this [Scheduled database polling with WSO2 Data Services Server](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2013/11/scheduled-database-polling-with-wso2-data-services-server/) blog on linux Ubuntu with WSO2 DSS 3.0.1 and ESB 4.7.
0

While i am inserting the values into  **student_registration table**,

Nothing displaying in WSO2 ESB terminal side  and WSO2 DSS terminal side.
Scheduling in not working, some one please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share your DB content, you need to have an intial timestamp set in the timestamp table

Answer (score 0):

If you inserted any baseline timestamp record into "timestamp table" ?

***Ex.***

> insert into imestamp_table(ID, timestamp) values (1, SYSDATE());